# Lashon HaRa and friend

Tags: lashon-hara-slander

My friend wants to work at this place that I worked at. It was a highly toxic place. Every other employee there also felt the same about its toxicity.
As far as lashon hara goes, can I tell him in one sentence that he should not work there?
Or does Halacha expect me to sit back and let things go their way?

I am very strict about Lashon HaRa, cause i read that there was once a king who did all the aveiros possible except lashon hara....and he never lost a war or something. I very much keep that story in my mind always.

Comment: I think this qualifies as asking for a practical ruling. Ask a Rabbi what you should and shouldn't say. The Chofetz Chaim Heritage Foundation runs a specific hotline for these issues at 718.951.3696.  Link here: https://cchf.global/about-us/hotlines/

Comment: This might be helpful: https://seferchofetzchaim.wordpress.com/2011/08/08/dcompanion-the-seven-rules-of-toeles/

Answer (score 1):

This would be letoeles, for a purpose, and you could definitely tell him. But you have to be sure that it isn't motzei shem ra, spreading falsehoods. It you really unbiasly know that it is true, then you not only can tell him, you should tell him.

Comment: You may be interested in one of the many transalations of the sefer Chofetz Chaim - you can see a bunch here https://www.pardes.ca/catalogsearch/result/?q=chofetz+chaim

Comment: Toeles is not a blanket heter. There are many other conditions that must be fulfilled.

Comment: To add to what @N.T. said, you can't harbor negative thoughts about the subject of your speech, you have to have *rebuked the subject first*, and there has to be *no other way* of obtaining the desired result (friend not working there) than saying the lashon hara. And even then you can only say the minimum amount. Something like "you don't want to work there" can do (assuming the other person won't assume any worse than it actually is from that sentence). Tone and facial expressions matter as well, and you can't exaggerate. It really isn't that simple.

Comment: That's assuming we're dealing with people who are subject to the laws of Lashon Hara.